# Getting llvm-cov to talk to codecov.io

Tags: code-coverage, codecov, llvm-cov

I'm in the process of (finally!) setting up code coverage monitoring for my brand new C++ project. Due to the fact that I need some advanced C++20 features (read, coroutines), I am using `clang 6` as compiler.

Now, I followed [this guide](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/SourceBasedCodeCoverage.html) on how to do basic code coverage for your project, and everything worked like magic. If I do:

```
clang++ -fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping test.cpp -o test.out
LLVM_PROFILE_FILE="coverage/test.profraw" ./test.out
llvm-profdata merge -sparse coverage/test.profraw -o coverage/test.profdata
llvm-cov show ./test.out -instr-profile=coverage/test.profdata
```

I get a nice, colored report on my terminal that tells me what is covered and what is not.

So far so good! I thought I was close to what I wanted, but then the pain started when I tried to get the report uploaded to [codecov.io](https://codecov.io).

I have tried a few things, including:

- Running their `https://codecov.io/bash` script on my `coverage` folder in the hope that maybe it would catch on my `test.profdata`. No dice, and it makes sense, since even `llvm-cov` needs the path to the executable file to run.
- Using the `export` functionality: when running `llvm-cov export --instr-profile=coverage/test.profdata ./test.out` I get a good-looking JSON file (via terminal). I tried throwing the output in a `coverage.json` file, which actually got uploaded, but then codecov just says that there was an error parsing it, with no further information.

I'm feeling completely lost. Everything seems so black-box-ish on their website that I just don't understand how to get anything done that doesn't by chance perfectly fit the cases that they can manage.

How can I get this working with codecov? If codecov can't handle my reports, is there any other equivalent online code coverage that I can use to get this to work?

Answer (score 8):

It looks like the bash script codecov uses to upload coverage data to their site looks for files matching a wide range of patterns associated with formats that it understands. These are poorly documented, but you can at least see which patterns are viable by looking at [the script on Github](https://github.com/codecov/codecov-bash/blob/master/codecov). Of course, this doesn't tell you what expectations codecov has about the format of files matching a given pattern, as you discovered when your `coverage.json` file was rejected.

Through trial and error I have found that the following produces a file that codecov will interpret correctly when you run the bash script:

`llvm-cov show ./test.out -instr-profile=default.profdata > coverage.txt`

I haven't extensively tested what file names are allowed, but it seems that you can put whatever additional characters you want between `coverage` and `.txt` in the name of the file that you're piping the coverage data to (e.g. you could call it `coverage_my_file_name.txt`).

EDIT: Just in case this is helpful to anyone, it turns out that an important corollary to the above is that it's critical that you avoid naming anything that isn't a coverage report something that matches this pattern. I just dealt with a scenario where I had a bunch of executables named coverage_[more_text_here].out that were getting uploaded with the reports. It turns out that attempting to parse assembly code as a coverage report can cause codecov to mysteriously fail without any useful errors.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use GCOV profiling, which is a little less precise than source-based, but it is supported by codecov.io. You need the "--coverage" compiler flag to enable it.

You can use [grcov](https://crates.io/crates/grcov) (which you can also download from https://github.com/mozilla/grcov/releases) to parse the gcno/gcda files and upload them via the codecov.io bash uploader:

```
grcov OBJ_DIR -s SRC_DIR -t lcov --branch > lcov.info
bash codecov.sh -f "lcov.info"
```

I'm planning to add support for source-based reports to grcov, which will make it easier to support the format on codecov too.